# nm reports symbol is defined but ldd reports symbol is undefined

Tags: linux, linker, shared-libraries

I'm having a linking problem.  I need to link against a shared library `libfoo.so` that depends on a function `read` which I would like to define myself in the file read.c.

I compile and link everything together but at runtime I get the error

```
/home/bar/src/libfoo.so: undefined symbol: sread.
```

nm reports the symbol is defined

```
$nm baz | grep sread
  00000000000022f8 t sread
```

but ldd reports the symbol is undefined

```
$ldd -r baz | grep sread 
undefined symbol: sread (/home/bar/src/libfoo.so)
```

What gives? Is there some isse with the fact that libfoo.so is a shared library?

Comment: Maybe you should post the full link lines for all your shared objects and executables to shed light on the subject.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

First, defining a function called 'read' is a bad idea(TM), because it is a standard libc function on all UNIXen. The behavior of your program is undefined when you do this.

Second, the `read` function you defined in `libbaz.so` is marked with a `'t'` in `nm` output. This means that this function is local (not visible outside `libbaz.so`). Global functions are marked with `'T'` by `nm`.

Did you use `'static int read(...)'` when you defined it in read.c?
If not, did you use a linker script, or `attribute((visibility(hidden)))`, or perhaps `-fvisibility=hidden` on command line when you compiled and linked `libbaz.so`?

Comment: the name of the function is not actually read, I was just trying to make things simple. 

Ahh... you are correct I am using -Wl,--version-script which includes a file that keeps all symbols local except two that I wish to export. I obviously need to export the read function as well.

Answer (score 1):

The above error can also occur when C code is compiled with G++, and then linked. G++ performs name mangling, so the actual symbol may be something like "_Zsds_[function_name]_", causing the linker to choke when it searches for the un-mangled name.

I ran into the same behavior today, except my issue was resolved following the actions outlined on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Name_mangling#Handling_of_C_symbols_when_linking_from_C.2B.2B). Basically, C code compiled with a C++ compiler will have a "mangled" name in the symbol table, causing C-style symbol resolution to fail.

Answer (score -1):

When you build your shared library you need to resolve **all** undefined symbols from either within the same library or another (shared) library. The linker will **not** resolve an undefined symbol from a library with a symbol from your application.

Comment: I should clarify that baz is actually a shared library. So does this mean I should create a shared library that contains only the read function, and link against this? Is there an explicit way to tell the linker to resolve the undefined symbols from the shared library libfoo.so with this other shared library (say libread.so)?

Comment: You are quite mistaken: the runtime loader will happily resolve undefined symbol from a shared libary with a symbol from the main executable, provided that symbol is "exported" in its dynamic table (which happens e.g. when the executable is linked with -rdynamic).

Comment: @codehippo you did not say that baz was a shared library and the name does not lead to that assumption either.

Comment: @Employed Russian It is very unusual to link executables with exported symbols and I did not assume that the OP was using this rare technique, as if he did he probably needed not to ask the question he did.